# How to achieve this shading/lighting

Tags: shaders, lighting

Can anyone help me to achieve similar color and lighting scheme as in the model below? So far, I've tried texture coordinate and color ramp nodes, couldn't get the desired result[image].

Comment: Could you share your blend file? Really helps to have a base starting point